# Magento Community 1.6.1; Users get empty response after products updated

Tags: session, magento, block, shopping-cart, session-cookies

Running Magento Community 1.6.1 on Apache, MySQL.

Hi, I have a huge problem with visitors getting locked out from our site by receiving empty response from server. Any user that has anything in the cart when any product is updated (actually just pressing save is enough), will get locked out by receiving empty_response from the web server. 
Users gain access again if they remove their session cookie, and/or we clear the sessions folder in /var/, but until then all they get is empty_response from the web server.

Rolling back the database to one a few days older than the first symptoms kills the problem, without having to replace any files. 
No logs or exceptions are produced.

It took a while to cause the problem, and even a bit longer to find the cause, so rolling back to a database backup from before the problem is not an option.

Have read a lot about cookie lifetimes, etc, but nothing of that has been related to this. Furthermore - being able to verify with a functional database allowed me to copy the settings (actually copying the content of core_config_data) from the functional database to a copy of the current live database, for more test. Results were the same…

So, ending up here… would be extremely thankful for any tips, hints or directions that put me on the right track!

Thanks for reading my post, and many thanks in advance for spending your time reflecting over this issue

Answer (score 0):

you should try

1. database repair tool
2. clear all logs in database
3. re-save customer groups
4. inspect cookie settings with fiddler or any other similar tool
5. verify that your server clock is correct
6. enable error messages
7. inspect server error logs to see if there is any logs related to this

Comment: 1. Ran Repair table for each table in database, no change. 2. I'm not sure which logs you mean, it would be amazing to get some more details :) 3. done (in customer|customer groups), no difference. 4. will do, 5. done - just in case - but since this is not changed when I swap database it is not a likely cause. 7. Waiting for the hosting company to send me logs :)

Comment: logs in database and it is not a proper hosting if you don't have access to error logs by default